# Flutter: Cannot set the status bar transparent with SliverAppBar

Tags: flutter

I am having a hard time setting Android's status bar to transparent. I tested with the following code and it works:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    ),
  );
  return Scaffold(
    body: Text('temporary test widget'),
  );
}
```

But when I substitute my correct widget in the body section of my `Scaffold`, the transparency is lost:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    ),
  );
  return Scaffold(
    body: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
          pinned: true,
          expandedHeight: 225.0,
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            background: Image(
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              excludeFromSemantics: false,
              image: AssetImage('images/aristocrat.jpg'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SliverFixedExtentList(
          itemExtent: 100.0,
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                color: Colors.lightBlue[100 * (index % 9)],
                child: Text('List Item $index'),
              );
            },
            childCount: 10,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 3.0**

This code works fine, this make the statusbar transparent, and the `Brightness.dark`, will take care of the rest.

**Pointer:** Also, if you want to use this, although, **it is not required**. But if nothing works out for you, please consider using [flutter_statusbarcolor](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_statusbarcolor) package

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, // this one will make the statusbar transparent
        statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark //this will take care of the icon color
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              // brightness: Brightness.dark, <-- Not required if you have mentioned in the above AnnotatedRegion
              pinned: true,
              expandedHeight: 225.0,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                background: Image(
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  excludeFromSemantics: false,
                  image: AssetImage('images/aristocrat.jpg'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverFixedExtentList(
              itemExtent: 100.0,
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    color: Colors.lightBlue[100 * (index % 9)],
                    child: Text('List Item $index'),
                  );
                },
                childCount: 10,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
   );
}
```

Comment: @user1506104 check the updated answer please, and let me know if that works

Comment: Can you show me the screenshot of your result @user1506104 ?

Comment: Hey @user1506104 try the new code, and let me know if that works out. Cos, this should work. If not, please share the screenshot, on what you are getting with the above code?

Comment: I have `SystemUiOverlayStyle` in other screens. Does that matter?

Comment: If it is replacing the screen, then yes, it matters, cos, it is overlapping the current definitions to the designs @user1506104 Remove other `SystemUiOverlayStyle`

Comment: I cannot remove it from other screens as I also want to change the status bar style in each screen.

Comment: thius is not work!!!